# i want to make the container have overflow hidden in column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have column and inside column i have 3 widget, HtmlWidget ,Transform.Scale, and HtmlWidget, inside Transform.Scale i have image, this is the code, i want make the image overflow from their top widget and bottom widget

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Container(
            //   child: HtmlWidget(
            //     """
            //             <div style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%;"><div><p>sdasdasdasdas</p><p><span style="font-size: 18px;">asdasdasdasdas</span></p><p style="margin-left:16px;" class="ql-indent-1"><strong>asdasdasdasdas</strong></p><p style="text-align:center;" class="ql-align-center"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 194, 102);">asdasdasdasd</span></p><ol><li>sdddsaasdasdsadasdasdasdas</li><li>eqweqweqweqwe</li></ol><p><br></p><ul><li>xdasdsadsadasdas</li><li>zxcxzcxzcxzczxczxcz</li></ul></div></div>
            //           """,
            //   ),
            // ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: HtmlWidget(
                """
                        <div style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%;"><div><p>sdasdasdasdas</p><p><span style="font-size: 18px;">asdasdasdasdas</span></p><p style="margin-left:16px;" class="ql-indent-1"><strong>asdasdasdasdas</strong></p><p style="text-align:center;" class="ql-align-center"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 194, 102);">asdasdasdasd</span></p><ol><li>sdddsaasdasdsadasdasdasdas</li><li>eqweqweqweqwe</li></ol><p><br></p><ul><li>xdasdsadsadasdas</li><li>zxcxzcxzcxzczxczxcz</li></ul></div></div>
                      """,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 100,
              child: Transform.scale(
                transformHitTests: true,
                scale: 3,
                child: Center(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/example.jpeg"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: HtmlWidget(
                """
                        <div style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%;"><div><p>sdasdasdasdas</p><p><span style="font-size: 18px;">asdasdasdasdas</span></p><p style="margin-left:16px;" class="ql-indent-1"><strong>asdasdasdasdas</strong></p><p style="text-align:center;" class="ql-align-center"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 194, 102);">asdasdasdasd</span></p><ol><li>sdddsaasdasdsadasdasdasdas</li><li>eqweqweqweqwe</li></ol><p><br></p><ul><li>xdasdsadsadasdas</li><li>zxcxzcxzcxzczxczxcz</li></ul></div></div>
                      """,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image: this is the result]

[image: this is what i expected]

after i change that code, the top still same

[image: still same]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Stack like this

```
Stack(
 children: <Widget>[
   Positioned.fill(
     child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child: Container(
         color: Colors.red,
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
         height: 100,
       ),
     ),
   ),
   Container(
     child: Transform.scale(
       transformHitTests: true,
       scale: 3,
       child: Center(
         child: Image(
           image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/example.jpeg"),
         ),
       ),
     ),
  ),
 ]
)
```

Comment: What do you mean for broken? @StevanusYohanes

Comment: Can you post also the new code, please? @StevanusYohanes